# Adding router.php in Joomla component breaks site

Tags: joomla, custom-component, joomla-sef-urls

I'm trying to add routing for a custom component I made and I followed the docs on how to do this. But when I uploaded the router.php file to the component, it rendered the site blank. Not sure if I'm missing anything. It's as if the whole site is referring only this new file, thus giving me a blank page.

The component's URL with SEF URL on is:

```
index.php/en/products
```

And the way I built the router is to have links look like these:

```
index.php/en/products/trousers
index.php/en/products/555-123-20
```

component\router.php

```
function componentBuildRoute( &$query )
{
    $segments = array();

    if(isset($query['view'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['view'];
        unset($query['view']);
    }
    if(isset($query['cat'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['cat'];
        unset($query['cat']);
    }
    if(isset($query['itemid'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['itemid'];
        unset($query['itemid']);
    }
    if(isset($query['color'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['color'];
        unset($query['color']);
    }

    return $segments;
}

function componentParseRoute($segments) {
    $vars = array();
    switch($segments[0])
    {
        case 'listing':
               $vars['view'] = $this->chooseView($segments[1]);
               break;
        case 'item':
               $vars['id'] = $segments[1].'-'.$segments[2];
               break;
    }
    return $vars;
}

private function chooseView($cat) {
    switch($cat) {
        case '1':
            $cat = 'trousers';
            break;
        case '2':
            $cat = 'jackets';
            break;
    }
    return $cat;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `private` keyword with a non-method function?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-method function"? This function is used within `componentParseRoute`.

Comment: Precisely, it is not a class method. Start by removing that keyword. And enable PHP errors during development, that would have prevented this one. Next, what is your component's name? It should prefix the function names: `function <Yourcomponentname>ParseRoute($segments) {` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MasterAM is correct about the `private`.

On a somewhat related note, `router.php` does not like variables sitting outside of functions. I tried to add a global array but it was not accessible. Instead I made a function to return the array.